# Tesseract-Android-Tools changes and modifications compiled successfully(i think) but no output

Tags: android, tesseract

Currently I am trying to get tesseract android tools

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/

to work for me on Android. I have been going at this for about a week to no avail.

I am running Win 7 64 bit with cygwin.

I followed the instructions in the readme file and made many changes to the Android.mk files. Basically it was appending a slash to the path, so I had to manually hard code the paths of the individual files, or move to location of the files within the 3 packages to get it to build. However at the end of the build, I did not recieve a "Build Sucessful" notice, but the .so files were generated.

I ported it to eclipse as is and used the following code to get the extracted text.

```
private static final String TESSBASE_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/";

Bitmap imageFile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();

        if(baseApi.init(TESSBASE_PATH, "eng")){
            System.out.println("Tessbase initialized");
            baseApi.setDebug(true);
            baseApi.setImage(bmp);
            String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
            System.out.println("---------------------output-------------------");
            System.out.println("recognizedText<"+recognizedText+">");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Tessbase initialization failure.");
        }
```

At first I was getting an error saying

> "Bitmap functions not available; library must be compiled under android-8 NDK"

After taking a look at the tessbaseapi.cpp file I realized that it needed a specific compiler flag to compile the correct function. This flag was -DHAS_JNIGRAPHICS. What I think this means is that the JNI Graphics library must be present.

Yet the program still wouldn't compile because the memcpy() function in the newly compiled method could not be found. I fixed this by changing the actual C++ code to include

Finally the program compiled fully (still wasn't getting a BUILD SUCCESSFUL notice though) and when I ran it, I did not get any output at all. This could be a problem with the eng.traineddata file, or could be a problem in the actual code.

Is there anything I have done wrong? Can someone link me to and eng.traineddata file that they know works and image that works with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few months since you posted this question, however if you're still looking for answers I would seriously recommend that you have a look at the [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) project on github.

Whilst this won't solve the error that you've posted, its a tactical work around/alternate solution.

It's a fork of tesseract-android-tools and is incredibly easy to use, you'll have it up and running within the hour.

If you're getting poor results, make sure that traineddata file is there, use DDMS file explorer to check its there and not 0 bytes (that happened to me a few times).

Also, make sure you set the whitelist and blacklist characters, this will improve results very well.

Good luck

Comment: I actually ended up doing this. I used the same tess-two project on github and built it from ubuntu. It works exactly the way I want it. I think it might have been a problem with the tesseract android tools library. I would recommend using tess-two for anyone experiencing similar difficulties.